# Xamarin.Android PDFViewer Library

Tags: xamarin.android

I am building an application with Xamarin.Android and have reports section where I generate reports in PDF and show to user.

I do not want to write my own PDF viewer since its not the main functionality. I was wondering if there is such library available?

I need to open PDF within app, so I cannot use external apps.

I tried [Xamarin.PdfView.Android](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.PdfView.Android/) but this library is not compatible with latest version of Xamarin.

Most of the PDFViewers are build for Xamarin.Forms but I need for Xamarin.Android

Answer (score 0):

You can show a pdf file within a webview. 
Inside the webview you will set the url from google drive and it will show the pdf.

Hope this help you

Comment: It looks more like comment then an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)